# Make bitmap drawable tile in x but stretch in y

Tags: android, android-view

I have an image which I'm using as a background for a RelativeLayout.  The image needs to be tiled horizontally to make a pattern.

I'm able to get the image to tile horizontally by using this code:

```
BitmapDrawable b3 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);

b3.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

v.findViewById(R.id.layout).setBackgroundDrawable(b3);
```

The problem is that the image also tiles vertically.  It seems to tile in the "clamp" mode in the vertical, but "repeat" mode in the horizontal.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: TileMode]

As you can see, the image is just a little bit smaller than the space it occupies, and the bottom edge is "clamped".

How can I set the image to stretch vertically but tile horizontally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method invokes creation of new bitmap but it looks like it's acrhiving your goal

```
        View view = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tile);
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int intrinsicHeight = bd.getIntrinsicHeight();
        Rect bounds = new Rect(0,0,width,intrinsicHeight);
        bd.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
        bd.setBounds(bounds);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(), bounds.height(), bd.getBitmap().getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        bd.draw(canvas);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        view.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

Please note that it only works if view was already layouted, so a method lile `onWindowFocusChanged` is a good place for this code.

Comment: Is possible to do that only by combining drawables XML's?

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution, Nikolay. Do we need to take care of Bitmaps or garbage collector will handle it after activity is destroyed?

Answer (score 2):

I feel it is straight forward:(This code will tile in Y and repeat in x)

In your onWindowFoucsChanged you call:

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Drawable d = getRepeatingBG(this, R.drawable.image_that_you_want_to_repeat);
        body_view.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

    }

private Drawable getRepeatingBG(Activity activity, int center)
    {   

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled=true;

        Bitmap center_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), center, options);
        center_bmp.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
        center_bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(center_bmp, dm.widthPixels , center_bmp.getHeight(), true);

        BitmapDrawable center_drawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(),center_bmp);
//change here setTileModeY to setTileModeX if you want to repear in X
        center_drawable.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        return center_drawable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Far too late for you, but may be useful for others.

You can create a custom View in order to do this. Simply scale your source bitmap to be as high as your view and then draw it repeatedly on the canvas:

```
public class RepeatingXImageView extends View {

Bitmap bitmap;
Paint paint;

public RepeatingXImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RepeatingXImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RepeatingXImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if(changed) {
        paint = new Paint();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.seekbar_overlay);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bottom - top, false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(bitmap == null) return;
    int left = 0;
    while(left < getWidth()) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, 0, paint);
        left += bitmap.getWidth();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem myself. Tried using 9patch image but it seems you cannot use 9patch images along with tiling, the 9patch stretches the image no matter what you define in the tiling property.
At the end what i will do is ask the creator of the image to stretch it vertically or do it myself. I would love a better solution if anyone finds one.